# Would you please show me what the latter sentence means in a more readily way?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Extracted from Wikipedia:

> World Book Capital is a title bestowed by UNESCO to a city in recognition of the quality of its programs to promote books and reading and the dedication of all players in the book industry.

Extracted from TehranTimes - a newspaper published in Tehran, Iran:

> UNESCO initiated the concept of World Book Capital city for the first time in 2001 in acknowledgement of the best programs dedicated to books and reading after selecting

If both sentences have the same meaning would you please analyse, especialy the latter, and explain or rephrase it in a more simple manner?

Any feed-back would be appreciated.

Comment: When I read *UNESCO initiated ... the best programs dedicated to books and reading after selecting* and it just stopped there, I asked myself, "Selecting what?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> UNESCO initiated the concept of World Book Capital city for the first
>   time in 2001 in acknowledgement of the best programs dedicated to
>   books and reading...

Who? UNESCO

Did what? *initiated the concept of World Book Capital City* (came up with the idea for a new honorary title "World Book Capital City")

When did they do it?  *for the first time in 2001* (the origin was in 2001)

Why did they do that? *in acknowledgement of the best programs* (to give recognition to the best programs = to praise them publicly)

What kind of programs? Programs which are *dedicated to books and reading*

*Dedicated to*  =  focusing much effort on / having the goal of

*books and reading* = making books available and encouraging people to read